# Meeting scheduler algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have created a function which, given an array of free/busy statuses `101100101110100` (where each 1 or 0 represents free/busy on a 30 minute interval), for each of `n` people in meeting, will output a score for how many people are free at that time.

```
Timeslot: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Person A: 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
Person B: 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
Meeting start: [Timeslot 5]
Meeting duration: [3 Timeslots]
Score: 5/6  (Sum availability / (duration * n people))
```

The implementation doesn't really matter, but basically given a meeting start time, it will output a score 0 - 100%  for how free on average the attendees are.

Finding the best meeting is easy; maximise the score over all possible start times, earlier the better in case of ties. The complexity here is that I want to schedule `m` meetings all at once, where the same person could be needed in 2 meetings. Now there is a risk that the meetings overlap, double booking someone.

2 approaches I have tried:

- In order, maximise the score of meeting 1. Then eliminate that from the search space and maximise the score of meeting 2. Repeat.

  - Issue: This finds a local maximum, which may be suboptimal if attendees of meeting 1 are very flexible, meeting 2 are much more busy, yet by booking meeting 1 first we may eliminate the best times for meeting 2
  - Could try different permutations of order in which meetings are booked and find the best, but still, this won't necessarily be the global maximum
- Create a large penalty for overlapping meetings, then book all meetings simultaneously, using the average score and an optimisation algorithm to maximise it.

  - Issue: I have not had good results using simulated annealing or the evolution solver built into Excel. The problem is non linear because people's schedules don't vary smoothly. But I think the bigger issue is if I start meeting 1 at timeslot x, if it overlaps meeting 2, then the score is really bad, if it doesn't overlap the score is really good. So the optimisation algorithm may get an unlucky score for some timeslot and never try it again. Basically the big penalty makes spikes in the the m-dimensional solution space that degrade the performance.

I'm trying to think of a way to penalise clashes while keeping everything nice and smooth.

Comment: This seems like the kind of question that's better suited for a discussion forum.